# Show some text and hide the rest

Tags: text, hide, show-hide

I want to show some text and hide some, without using overflow, because overflow will show a scrollbar and I do not want to see a scrollbar. I am building a music player web application, when playing a song I don't want to show all of the song title, just want to show some and fade hide the rest if it's a long title

I tried using css overflow but it also shows a scrollbar, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this tutorial:
https://www.w3schools.in/css3/css-marquee

As far as I understand your question, this should be the result you want to achieve.